# How to get a "sensible" graph view of branches in a Git repository?

Tags: git

Previously, I have worked on cvs, where there is a support of web and graph view.
So, if I open cvsweb, I can search the tags easily. Also, the best part is the graphical view. The graphical view clearly shows from where the branch was created. However, I can't see the same in git. Here are the two images. I have inserted the images to do the comparison. My question is how can I get the same graphical view of cvs in git. If not possible, how do I interpret the branch point etc. Is git complicated in the representation/ drawing conclusions? I am asking this question because many software engineers like me have to deal with regressions and releases. The objective here is to identify the branch point. Also, where the branches were merged - like merge point, etc. This gives an information like where and when the changes went.

[image]

In CVS, I can make out easily, from where the branches were created. 
Git Representation

Here is the git representation - I can't make out from where the branches were created. It looks took ugly. I can't make out anything.

[image]

Comment: You may look at [this](https://plasticscm.com/branch-explorer/index.html) (I'm not in any way affiliated with its vendor).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think git tortoise on windows is the best way to get a sensible graph.
Right click and Click Revision Graph.

Answer (score 0):

I think its hard to get an exactly the same view for git, however we can improve upon what you have now.

The following is taken from: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-in-Other-Environments-Graphical-Interfaces

When you install Git, you also get its visual tools, `gitk` and `git-gui`.

`gitk` is a graphical history viewer. Think of it like a powerful GUI shell over git log and git grep. This is the tool to use when you’re trying to find something that happened in the past, or visualize your project’s history.

If that doesn't suffice I would take a look at:

https://git-scm.com/download/gui/linux

Comment: Those graphs really are of not much value. I am looking for a clean graph like CVS.

Comment: `git gui` does no visualisation, `gitk` basically shows what the OP presented on their second screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

> I can't make out from where the branches were created

This information is not stored in git. All you know is to which commits are branches pointing *now*. Maybe merge commit messages may contain useful information like what was merged in what.

Comment: I wish that people add a meaningful git commit logs. However, it is not the case. Any other idea from you will be helpful?